# ckeditor replace word how add more?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I can change a word in ckeditor with this regex,

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.txtisi;     
var edata = editor.getData();    
var rep_text = edata.replace("INSERT INTO", "INSERT-INTO");    
editor.setData(rep_text);
```

but how to add more words that will replace, not only one word. i have try but i get the last word always. like this.editor = CKEDITOR.instances.txtisi;

```
var edata = editor.getData();
var rep_text = edata.replace("INSERT INTO", "INSERT-INTO"); // you could also 
var rep_text = edata.replace("DELETE TABLE", "DELETE-TABLE"); // you could also 
var rep_text = edata.replace("TRUNCATE TABLE", "TRUNCATE-TABLE"); // you could also use a regex in the replace 
editor.setData(rep_text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code

This is the fixed version

```
      var edata = editor.getData();
      var edata = edata.replace("INSERT INTO", "INSERT-INTO"); // you could also 
      var edata = edata.replace("DELETE TABLE", "DELETE-TABLE"); // you could also 
      var edata = edata.replace("TRUNCATE TABLE", "TRUNCATE-TABLE"); // you could also use a regex in the replace 
      editor.setData(edata);
```

The reason is that string.replace() returns a NEW string and leaves the old one unaffected. (Just like any string operations btw). So you need to update `edata` variable with fresh data after each call to `.replace()`